# How to pass an int or string to a command line argument

Tags: python, parsing, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to find a way of passing an int or a string to a specific command line argument but I understand that eveything passed into a command line is returned as a string, is there a way around this?

heres my code:

```
parser = ArgumentParser(
    description="Generate a simple presentation based on MTD file content"
    )
parser.add_argument(
    '-m',
    dest='mdd',
    help="Full path of target mdd",
    required=True,
    metavar="\"<data>.mdd\"",
    )
parser.add_argument(
    '-v',
    dest='version',
    help="The version (latest/active/basic or numerical version)",
    required=False,
    default='latest'
    )

args = parser.parse_args()

MDD_PATH = args.mdd
VERSION = args.version
```

Here's is what I type into the command line@

```
-m "C:\Users\xxxx\workspace\xxxx\src\Testing\Data\filename.mdd"
-v "22"
```

I would like -v to accept both ints and strings, it has a default property and can be bypassed if required but I need some help with allowing it to switch between ints and strings.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `type` argument you can also filter out invalid strings:

```
def parse_version(v):
    if v in ('latest', 'active', 'basic'):
        return v
    else:
        return int(v)   # this will error if v is non-numeric, causing the
                        # parser to reject the argument

parser.add_argument(
    '-v',
    dest='version',
    help="The version (latest/active/basic or numerical version)",
    required=False,
    default='latest',
    type=parse_version
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To the command line, everything is a string. You program cannot tell the difference between:

```
program -v "22"
```

and

```
program -v 22
```

Quotes are used by the shell to escape spaces in arguments.

---

In your python code, you can try to convert it to an int:

```
VERSION = args.version
try:
    VERSION = int(VERSION)
except ValueError:
    pass
```

Comment: @Boosted_d16: The second half of my answer

Comment: that works...although I used the isdigit() method on the string. Thanks!

Comment: Why not use the keyword `type` that's here for conversions ?

Comment: @bvidal: Wasn't aware it took custom functions

Comment: @Eric in this case you don't even need a custom function since `int(22)` and `int("22")` will work just fine.

Comment: @bvidal: _"The version (**latest/active/basic** or numerical version)"_

Answer (score 0):

You can use the keyword argument `type` of the [add_argument method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#type). It defines a way to convert the command line arguments to pretty much anything that you want either using built-in type or callbacks.
It provides better error handling and is the preferred way of doing "type-checking" for the command line.

Comment: Agreed, I am now using the type argument. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I like to use a generic helper function I typically call `tryconvert`. Given a value and a list of types (or any callable, really) it tries converting the value to each type and returns the first conversion that works. If all of them fail, the original value is returned.

```
def tryconvert(value, *types):
    for t in types:
        try:
            return t(value)
        except ValueError, TypeError:
            pass
    return value
```

This can be used with the `type` argument on your `add_argument` call like so:

```
parser.add_argument(
    '-v',
    dest='version',
    help="The version (latest/active/basic or numerical version)",
    required=False,
    default='latest',
    type=lambda v: tryconvert(v, int)
)
```

You could have it return some other value if the parsing to a number fails (e.g. `None`) simply by passing a function that always returns `None` as the last argument to `tryconvert()`. This "conversion" will always succeed so the value will be returned if no other conversions work. If you are using `tryconvert` a lot, it is convenient to write a helper function that generates such functions for readability's sake:

```
def default(value):
    return lambda *a: value

parser.add_argument(
    '-v',
    dest='version',
    help="The version (latest/active/basic or numerical version)",
    required=False,
    default='latest',
    type=lambda v: tryconvert(v, int, default(None))
)
```